# Can't POST JSON using Volley

Tags: java, android, json, post, android-volley

I've searched a lot but can't find out what's happening. I wrote many variations of this code and here is the most recent one.

**Android code**

```
private static void post(@NonNull String url,
                         @NonNull Context context,
                         @NonNull final JSONObject jsonRequest,
                         @NonNull final ServerConnectionAdapter serverConnectionAdapter){
    Log.d(TAG, "post: URL = " + url);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            jsonRequest,
            serverConnectionAdapter,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    serverConnectionAdapter.onErrorResponse(null, error);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            // map.put("user", json.toString());
            map.put("user", "{\"id\":-1,\"name\":\"Gustavo Araujo\"}");
            return map;
        }
    };

    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

**Server (Java) code**

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("doPost");
    System.out.println("REQUEST: ");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()){
        System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + java.util.Arrays.toString(e.getValue()));
    }

    System.out.println("end");
}
```

**doPost method output**

```
doPost
REQUEST: 
end
```

I've been starring my screen for so long that I think I can't find where is the error. I did find many examples, with and without the getParams(). I tried both, and didn't change anything.

The `ServerConnectionAdapter` is an abstract class that I created to unify the response with the error listener. I am sure that it is not the problem because it does work flawlessly with the GETs that I have.

The `String url` also can't be wrong (otherwise the server wouldn't have been triggered.

The `jsonRequest` also isn't the problem because I already used `null` there and didn't change the results at all.

As I said, I've been starring this code for hours, all my assumptions may be completely wrong, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Does it showing any errors or any warnings in Log-cat in Android Studio?

Comment: [Method calling post](http://imgur.com/7lmRvNK) and the [output](http://imgur.com/xRrafOP). The rest of the output is just my own log to verify other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. The way that I wrote the `doPost` method I was reaching the request parametes, like when you access `http://localhost:8080/something?key=value` what is not what I intend to do.
I needed to read the body of the request. To do so, in Java, it should be as the code below:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Get the body of the request
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

    // Print each line
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Thank you for Zohaib Hassan for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The error photo you posted in comment in telling me that your request was successful, there isn't any issue from mobile side. The issue is from server side. Because when you are making the request it's going on server but your server is not returning any proper Json. It's returning nothing that's why you are getting that exception. Android request needs a Json in return but you are server is not returning that.

There is a possibility that the issue can be from app side and the cause for that is that maybe you are not sending the proper parameters to server. But as far as I can see, the main issue is from server side. Because all these exceptions are not handled on server side. Like when the parameters are wrong it should return a json with message telling you that the parameters are wrong.

Comment: I understand that and it is not the problem now. I want to know why the server isn't receiving any JSON from android. As I posted the output from server side is empty but the POST on android side seems to be right.

Comment: I am App Developer, I don't know much about server side. But I'll do some research and try to figure out. I'll get back to you if I find any solution.